# Python3 environments created from Anaconda 2.7 fails

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I have Anaconda 2 installed, so my base python version is 2.7. I can create all sorts of virtual envs using

```
conda create --name new_27 python=2.7
```

And the environment works just as expected after activating it. But if I install python version 3.x, it fails. The install goes without warning and I can activate it. But running anything there yields the following error message (doesn't matter what I run, I always get the same error message)

```
(py36) C:\Users\ist>pip list
Error processing line 1 of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\configparser-3.5.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\reprlib\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    __boot()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\site.py", line 47, in __boot
    addsitedir(item)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site.py", line 178, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
    import collections
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\reprlib\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

Comment: How did you install Python 3 (manually / Anaconda)? What did you put on the `PATH`?

Comment: conda create --name py36 python=3.6

Comment: (py36) C:\Users\ist>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\py36\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2;

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your Python 3 conda environment might be trying to access packages in your base environment.

These steps should tried to remedy that by removing the Python 3 environment; cleaning up any residual packages; update conda; and then re-creating the environment.

```
conda env remove -n py36
conda clean -tipsy
conda update conda -y
conda create -n py3 python=3.6
```

If this does not work, you may have to reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: I had to reinstall anaconda to get it to work. Thank you.